# MB 320 CDi L, can we use Idemitsu 0W20?

Tags: mercedes-benz, cdi

At the dealership they recommended 0W30 from Idemitsu Kosan. I have cartons of 0W20 which I use on our other Honda cars. I’ve never tried it on our S Class, what damage if any will be caused to this W221 motor?

Answer (score 0):

Your manual will state the needed oil specifications (yes, specifications not brand names) that the car needs. If you can find one of the mentioned approvals on the oil package, the oil is fine for this car. If not, the oil is not suited

Comment: After discussing this with my cousin who drives the W222, 0W20 made the engine louder and resulted in better Fuel Efficiency. Both meet the new MB 229.71 standard. So just the rating isn’t enough the grade is tallied  based on the Climate and terrain, this is what the dealership explained. I went with 0W40 MB 229.71, I was afraid at 8.7 cSt at operational temp the oil would be too thin. The MB standard specifically is for SPAsh. This time I stayed away from our regular MB 0W30 229.5, and opted for 0W40. I didn’t want the engine rattling sound at 20 weight.